# Can't alter my text in a <h1> using the getElementID

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

This is my html and JS code of the  that I'm trying to change, I've called the function and I have other methods within that startGame function that works properly however, I'm not able to alter the :

```js
var players = [];

function startGame() {

  players[0] = prompt("Player 1's name");
  players[1] = prompt("Player 2's name");

  document.getElementById("player1Name").innerText = players[0];
  document.getElementById("player2Name").innerText = players[1];
}
```

```html
<body onload="startGame();">
 <div class="Player1">
 
   <h1 id="player1Name"> Player One </h1>
 
 </div>
 
 <div class="Player2">
   <h1 id="player2Name"> Player Two </h1>
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('player1Name').innerHTML = 'whatever you want'` should work

Comment: are you calling `startGame()`?

Comment: what is the problem? Your code works just fine. just call `startGame()`

Comment: I have other code in that function that's working properly as I did call it and that's why this is driving me nuts.

Comment: What are you saying? Tested your code and it works just fine. Just call the function startGame().

Comment: Everyone, please vote to close this question as the issue here can't be reproduced, without providing further debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

check this code and click **Change**

```
<script>
    var players = [];

function startGame() {

  players[0] = prompt("Player 1's name");
  players[1] = prompt("Player 2's name");

  document.getElementById("player1Name").innerText = players[0];
  document.getElementById("player2Name").innerText = players[1];
}
</script>
<a onclick="startGame()">Change</a>
<div class="Player1">
  <h1 id="player1Name"> Player One </h1>
</div>
<div class="Player2">
  <h1 id="player2Name"> Player Two </h1>
</div>
```